# Check if a property is animated or has a driver

Tags: animation, python, drivers

Using python, how can I check to see if some property (like `context.object.location`) has any keyframes, or has a driver attached?

Comment: This usage of the api might give some pointers http://blendersushi.blogspot.de/2013/06/python-driving-arrays-like-boss.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A keyframe check could be done like this:

```
import bpy

def has_keyframe(ob, attr):
    anim = ob.animation_data
    if anim is not None and anim.action is not None:
        for fcu in anim.action.fcurves:
            if fcu.data_path == attr:
                return len(fcu.keyframe_points) > 0
    return False

print(has_keyframe(bpy.context.object, "location"))
```

But don't think there is an easy way to test for drivers.

Comment: drivers can be done similarly with ob.animation_data.drivers - thanks :)

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could access drivers that easily. You could extend my `has_keyframe()` function so it handles single properties as well (e.g. `location.x`), but it should work for array properties already.

Answer (score 2):

What we call "drivers" are technically "driven f-curves" attached through a Python object's `animation_data` attribute, just like action data. In an object, those attributes are present in *the object itself*, its *data* (whatever type it is), [*shape keys*](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Key.html#bpy.types.Key.animation_data), [*particle settings*](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.ParticleSettings.html#bpy.types.ParticleSettings.animation_data), [*materials*](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Material.html#bpy.types.Material.animation_data) and [*textures*](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.types.Texture.html#bpy.types.Texture.animation_data). So we need to check those places to know if there's any driver.

The following sample code is adapted from my driver-copying [operator](https://github.com/adhihargo/rigging_tools/blob/1fcf98cbdc663beca7ef15995fb37b26e78bbb37/rigging_tools.py#L1110), it merely prints the data paths of available animation and driver f-curves:

```
import bpy

def main():
    obj = bpy.context.active_object

    # Collect places where animation/driver data possibly present.
    keyable_list = [getattr(obj.data, 'shape_keys', None)]
    for ms in obj.material_slots:
        if not ms:
            continue
        keyable_list.append(ms.material)
        for ts in ms.material.texture_slots:
            if not ts:
                continue
            keyable_list.append(ts.texture)
    for ps in obj.particle_systems:
        keyable_list.append(ps.settings)
    keyable_list.append(obj)
    keyable_list.append(obj.data)

    # Print data paths of available animation/driver f-curves.
    for keyable in keyable_list:
        if not keyable or not keyable.animation_data:
            continue
        action = keyable.animation_data.action
        for fc in keyable.animation_data.drivers:
            print(fc.data_path)
        if action:
            for fc in action.fcurves:
                print(fc.data_path)

main()
```

I'm keeping it simple, but it's possible to extract only the name of the attribute using e.g. regular expression, if one needs to.

Comment: Good answer - but a bit over complicated for my needs - thanks anyway :)

Comment: @GregZaal: Great if you've found a solution. If a code doesn't capture all drivers in an object, just note that there are several places in the object that contains `animation_data`.